# C# Reflection Tree

Tags: c#, reflection

I"m try to find something similar to the treeview built into Visual Studio that lets you traverse a class.  Is there a basic library/class that basically contains a tree with Reflected data that iterates through a class and its subclasses?  I want code, I'm not interested in separate applications.

I don't think it would be that difficult to implement with reflection, but I'm hoping somebody else has already done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want ot iterate through nested class here is an example

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (DateTime));
        foreach (var exportedType in assembly.GetExportedTypes())
        {
            var parentNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add(exportedType.Name);
            AddNodes(exportedType, parentNode);
        }
    }

    private void AddNodes(Type type,TreeNode node)
    {
        foreach (var nestedType in type.GetNestedTypes())
        {
            var nestedNode = node.Nodes.Add(nestedType.Name);
            AddNodes(nestedType, nestedNode);
        }
    }
```

Maybe you also want some info about Methods , Properties e.t.c in that case you can use

```
    type.GetProperties();
    type.GetMethods();
    type.GetMembers();
    type.GetEvents();
    type.GetInterfaces();
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that you stated that you want code, but let me start by mentioning a tool called .Net reflector.  Until recently, it was the go-to tool for every .Net developer for doing what you are talking about.  It was taken over by red-gate a few years back, and they recently stated that they are going to start charging for it.

Because red-gate is going to charge for reflector, quite a few open source projects are ramping up development for a replacement. If I had to predict the future, I'd say that ILSpy has the best chance of succeeding because its being put out by the SharpDevelop team.

ILSpy: [ILSpy Info Page](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx)

Answer (score 1):

When searching for subclasses, first thing you need is to define boundaries. Are you searching for subclasses within a specific assembly? If yes, then this is the code you'll need:

```
    Type t = typeof(System.Nullable);
    System.Reflection.Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly("System.DLL");
    Type[] types = a.GetTypes();
    foreach (Type type in types)
    {
        if (type.IsSubclassOf(t))
            Console.Write(type.ToString());
    }
```

In the code above, it searches for all subclasses of Nullable in System.DLL. To get the subclasses within the current assembly, simply get the current assembly using

```
a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
```

The `Type` class provides a lot of information. So does the `Assembly` class.